# Is it okay if I store database files and other user created files within a TimesTen instance tree?

Tags: file, timesten

I am setting up a TimesTen in-memory database installation and I am wondering if it is okay to store the actual database files, and maybe some other user created files, within the directory tree of the actual TimesTen instance (as it would be convenient).

Answer (score 0):

No. The **only** files that should be present within the instance tree are files that are part of the instance, files generated by TimesTen and the defined configuration files that you create/modify such as the **sys.odbc.ini** file. You should also maintain a backup of your configuration files elsewhere.

Any files not mentioned above, including database files, may be removed without warning during a software upgrade. This is especially true for TimesTen Scaleout.